# Added a playground to my workspace, then deleted it. Now I have warnings I can't get rid of

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

In my workspace, I added a playground, tested some code, then deleted the  playground after deciding that it wasn't really that useful. Unfortunately, it seems to have left something behind:

```
/Users/GoldenJoe/Development/Xcode/MyApp/MyApp/MyPlayground.playground:18:11: Expression implicitly coerced from 'URLRequest?' to Any
```

Searching in Build Settings, I can't find anything related to playgrounds. How can I get rid of these annoying warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, had to solve it by opening the .xcworkspace file in a text editor and manually editing out all "MyPlayground" related blocks.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and could solve it with cleaning the project --> Xcode > Product > Clean .  To avoid these kind of problems I highly recommend you to use version control like GitHub to jump back to older versions of your code.